# asp.net The process cannot access the file with File.Copy and File.Delete

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using simple `File.Copy` and `File.Delete` basically first I copy my file from one folder to another than I call `File.Delete` to Delete From Previous folder but when compiler comes on `File.Delete` it give me error of

> The process cannot access the file with File.Copy and File.Delete

My code is.

```
  if (!Directory.Exists(copyPath))
            {
                File.Copy(filefullpath, copyPath);
                File.Delete(filefullpath);
            }
```

although it copy file into copyPath but delete is giving error.

Comment: Complie error or runtime error? Apparently a runtime error...

Comment: Very [related reading from raymond chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/09/07/10347136.aspx). Do you have anti virus enabled? Disable it and see if that works.

Comment: yes run time error like The process cannot access the file

Comment: which exception do you get?

Comment: I'm guessing that you program is throwing an excepcion. In wich line? `File.Copy` OR `File.Delete`? It cannot be both! Are you sure that `filefullpath` isn't open in another part of your code or maybe by another application?

Comment: Why not File.Move, which does both actions in a single command.

Comment: Is there anything earlier in the code that inspects the file in any way? If so, are the objects used there `Dispose`-able, and if so, have they been disposed? That is, look elsewhere in your code to see if you might be holding a lock on the file.

Comment: there is only File.Copy and File.Delete . File.Copy is working File.Delete Is not working my question is why i cant use both of them at same time

Answer (score 1):

Try `File.Move`

```
if (!File.Exists(copyPath))
{
     File.Move(filefullpath, copyPath); // Try to move
}
```

Comment: you should use File.Exist , not Directory

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this an UnauthorizedAccessException exception? Check if the appropriate users (IIS_IUSRS) have CRUD-rights in the folder.
File.Move can cause problems with inheritance of NTFS rights